# Speaker, Sound, mic, bluetooth, video nothing is working after update from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: apt, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa

```
System:
  Host: af Kernel: 6.5.0-15-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    Desktop: GNOME 42.9 tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 42.0
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Convertible System: HP
    product: HP Spectre Folio Convertible 13-ak0xxx v: Type1ProductConfigId
    serial: <superuser required> Chassis: type: 31
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 8503 v: 14.42 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI-[Legacy]: Insyde v: F.15 date: 03/26/2019
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 36.4 Wh (100.0%) condition: 36.4/54.3 Wh (67.0%)
    volts: 8.6 min: 7.7 model: COMPAL PABAS0241231 type: Li-ion serial: 41167
    status: Full
  Device-1: hid-0018:04F3:284A.0001-battery model: ELAN2514:00 04F3:284A
    serial: N/A charge: N/A status: Discharging
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Core i7-8500Y bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    smt: enabled arch: Amber/Kaby Lake note: check rev: 9 cache: L1: 128 KiB
    L2: 512 KiB L3: 4 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 615 high: 963 min/max: 400/4200 cores: 1: 400 2: 963
    3: 700 4: 400 bogomips: 12799
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 615 vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915
    v: kernel ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1, DP-2, HDMI-A-1, HDMI-A-2
    bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:591c class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Quanta HP Wide Vision FHD Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 1-9:3 chip-ID: 0408:5251 class-ID: 0e02 serial: 01.00.00
  Display: wayland server: X.org v: 1.21.1.4 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: gpu: i915 display-ID: 0
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: AU Optronics res: 3840x2160 dpi: 333
    size: 293x165mm (11.5x6.5") diag: 336mm (13.2") modes: 3840x2160
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 615 (AML-KBL)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: snd_soc_skl v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:9d71
    class-ID: 0401
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.5.0-15-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel pcie:
    speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 6e:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:24fd class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: a4:c3:f0:f7:58:2d
  IF-ID-1: wwan0 state: down mac: N/A
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-3:2 chip-ID: 8087:0a2b class-ID: e001
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: A4:C3:F0:F7:58:31
    bt-v: 2.1 lmp-v: 4.2 sub-v: 100 hci-v: 4.2 rev: 100
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 229.07 GiB (24.0%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLB1T0HALR-000H1
    size: 953.87 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: S3WSNX0KC04481
    rev: EXA73H1Q temp: 24.9 C scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 937.33 GiB used: 229.06 GiB (24.4%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 512 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8 C pch: 32.5 C mobo: 27.8 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 246 Uptime: 18m wakeups: 1687 Memory: 15.37 GiB
  used: 2.51 GiB (16.3%) Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A
  Packages: 1983 apt: 1950 snap: 33 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16
  running-in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.13
```

Comment: Can you `sudo apt install inxi` Then run `inxi -Fxxxzc0` then edit the post to include inxi results

Comment: @Jeremy31 system info is pasted above

Comment: Hai @Jeremy31 I feel it is because of window + HP some kind of agreement that Ubuntu is giving issue at the boot, I am pasting above the info menu/log. as I am facing issue with screen keyboard, sound, mic/speaker (external & internal) touchscreen, mousepad buttons, screen pen in short everything. 
the code is used **journalctl | grep -i "error\|warn\|fail\|acpi"**