# Touchscreen + Laptop pen is not working on HP Spectre Folio Convertible 13-ak0xxx

Tags: touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

Even I try to search for details but there are not much information about this specific touch screen issue, HP Spectre Folio Convertible 13-ak0xxx.
After I change ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 my laptop touch screen is not working, in tablet mood I can not see the screen keyboard also.
below you can find more information about my computer.

```
System:
  Kernel: 6.2.0-39-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.9
    tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 42.0
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Convertible System: HP
    product: HP Spectre Folio Convertible 13-ak0xxx v: Type1ProductConfigId
    serial: <superuser required> Chassis: type: 31
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 8503 v: 14.42 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Insyde
    v: F.15 date: 03/26/2019
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 12.7 Wh (31.9%) condition: 39.8/54.3 Wh (73.2%)
    volts: 8.4 min: 7.7 model: COMPAL PABAS0241231 type: Li-ion
    serial: <filter> status: Charging
  Device-1: hid-0018:04F3:284A.0001-battery model: ELAN2514:00 04F3:284A
    serial: N/A charge: N/A status: Discharging
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Core i7-8500Y bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    smt: enabled arch: Amber/Kaby Lake note: check rev: 9 cache: L1: 128 KiB
    L2: 512 KiB L3: 4 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 925 high: 1600 min/max: 400/4200 cores: 1: 700 2: 700
    3: 1600 4: 700 bogomips: 12799
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 615 vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915
    v: kernel ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1, DP-2, HDMI-A-1, HDMI-A-2
    bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:591c class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Quanta HP Wide Vision FHD Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 1-9:3 chip-ID: 0408:5251 class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter>
  Display: wayland server: X.org v: 1.21.1.4 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: gpu: i915 display-ID: 0
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: AU Optronics res: 3840x2160 dpi: 333
    size: 293x165mm (11.5x6.5") diag: 336mm (13.2") modes: 3840x2160
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 615 (AML-KBL)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: snd_soc_skl v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:9d71
    class-ID: 0401
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.2.0-39-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel pcie:
    speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 6e:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:24fd class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: wwan0 state: down mac: N/A
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-3:2 chip-ID: 8087:0a2b class-ID: e001
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 2.1 lmp-v: 4.2 sub-v: 100 hci-v: 4.2 rev: 100
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 187.83 GiB (19.7%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLB1T0HALR-000H1
    size: 953.87 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 type: SSD serial: <filter>
    rev: EXA73H1Q temp: 31.9 C scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 479.38 GiB used: 24.77 GiB (5.2%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 92.5 MiB used: 6 MiB (6.5%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
  ID-3: /home size: 438.95 GiB used: 163.05 GiB (37.1%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p4
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 18.63 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%)
    priority: -2 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8 C pch: 43.0 C mobo: 27.8 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 264 Uptime: 2h 19m wakeups: 10110 Memory: 15.5 GiB
  used: 4.17 GiB (26.9%) Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers:
  gcc: 11.4.0 alt: 11/12 Packages: 2148 apt: 2122 snap: 26 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 running-in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.13

===========================================================
$ dpkg --list|grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-91-generic              5.15.0-91.101                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                        5.15.0.91.88                                  amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Comment: Was everything working in 20.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using the HWE kernel uses the 5.15 kernel; you can use that too with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as it's the GA stack for 22.04. I note 6.2 kernel in your paste which is the current HWE kernel (will soon move to 6.5), you likely were using HWE back on 20.04 if you *release-upgraded* to 22.04. I'd boot 22.04(.1) media using the 5.15 kernel & try; but both kernel stacks can co-exist (*unless using specific closed-source kernel modules such as some nvidia I didn't see in your paste*)  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Thanks @ArchismanPanigrahi I installed HWE for 20.04 but no positive resulte with this also, and Yes before touchscreen/ screen touch worked properly with 20.04 but after upgrade Touchscreen is not working (I am unable to use PEN on screen) further more with this update builtin speaker/ mic is also not working. only external headset/headphone set is working. this new update put me in deep sh**.

Comment: the code i used **sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04**

Comment: Can you give 23.10 a try (just boot the live usb without installing) and let us know if it works?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi same issue while using 23.10.1, no touchscreen, no computer pen no screen rotation, further more laptop mic/ speakers are also not working.

Comment: @guiverc with linux-generic-hwe-20.04 still the problem remains as before.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi some days back I found this issue, which I feel the main [root for all issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1489926/speaker-sound-mic-bluetooth-video-nothing-is-working-after-update-from-20-04?noredirect=1#comment2609955_1489926), do you guys can help me out, is there is anyway to solve this while loading the system.